# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'i.replace(et,"<$1></$2>")')

Tags: jquery

Strangely enough I couldn't find the answer to this problem, but, I'm getting this error:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'i.replace(et,"<$1></$2>")')`

It appears to be coming from this line of code (I had to painstakingly comment every line of code to find it):

```
$.post("include/ajax.php", {updateWorkArt:"1", title:title, height:height, width:width, medium:medium, type:type, id:id, left:fin, top:top}, function(data){},"json");
```

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#updateWorkPopup", function(){
        var title = $("#updateWorkTitle").val();
        var height = $("#updateWorkHeight").val();
        var width = $("#updateWorkWidth").val();
        var medium = $("#updateWorkMedium").val();
        var type = $("#updateWorkAssetType").val();

        var id = $("#whiteBgPopup").attr("data-workid");

        if($.trim(title) != "" && $.trim(height) != "" && $.trim(width) != "" && $.trim(medium) != "" && $.trim(type) != "")
        {
            var left = parseInt($("#offsetContainer").position().left);

            var containerMid = parseInt($(window).width()/2);

            var fin = (-containerMid+left)*-1;

            var top = parseInt($("#wall").height()/2);

            $.post("include/ajax.php", {updateWorkArt:"1", title:title, height:height, width:width, medium:medium, type:type, id:id, left:fin, top:top}, function(data){
                if(data.success)
                {   
                    $("#popUp").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                        $("#popUp").find("input").each(function(){
                            $(this).val("").blur();
                        });

                        $("#wall").append("<div class='adjustArtwork' data-workid='" + id + "' style='left:" + fin + "px; top:" + top + "px;' ><img src='" + data.image + "' width='" + data.width + "' /></div>", function(){
                            alert("finished");
                        });
                    });
                }
                alert("yes!");
            },"json");
        }
    });
```

What does this error mean exactly?

Comment: It means that you're trying to call `undefined` like a function (eg. `undefined()`).  This could happen if you're not passing an argument where a function is expected.  Could you post your full code?

Comment: "I had to painstakingly comment every line of code to find it" --- open chrome dev tools and turn on "pause on uncaught exceptions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It appears that `.append()` does not have a callback function and was causing an error because it is `undefined`.

Thankfully though, `.append()` is synchronous so my code will load in the order it is written; no `function()` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It means (most likely) that your variable `i` referenced an object that does not have a property called `replace`.

When you asked for

```
i.replace
```

JavaScript looked up the value of `i` and found it to be an object; then looked up its `replace` property and didn't find it, so it returned `undefined`.

Then it tried to call `i.replace` as a function, but "undefined is not a function".

It is also possible that the value of `i.replace` actually was the value `undefined` (though this is rare and added only for completeness).

In either case, the code

```
i.replace(et,"<$1></$2>")
```

only works if the value of `i.replace` is a function.

Comment: I updated my question adding the block of code this problem pertains to.